# Why doesn't the distribution involve degrees of freedom even when the test statistic (Z) includes the sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

My question is related to the answer for the question here [What are the degrees of freedom of a distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35021/what-are-the-degrees-of-freedom-of-a-distribution), which implicates that whether some tests $(\chi^2, F)$ use degrees of freedom and some others don't $(Z)$ is determined by if the test statistic depends on the sample size, the number of groups, or both.

However, there are examples of $Z$ statistics that use the sample size in estimation but still follow, say, $Z$ distribution and thus don't involve the degrees of freedom. One case is the testing of independent population means with known population variances. The test statistic is given by:

$Z=\frac{(\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2})-(\mu_{D,0})}{\sigma_{(\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2})}}\sim N(0,1)$

in which:

$\sigma_{(\bar{X_1}-\bar{X_2})}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma^2_2}{n_2}}$

$\mu_{D,0}$ is the difference of hypothesized population means.

How should I differentiate these circumstances?

Comment: We should keep in mind that tests (speaking of those you probably have in mind :-) ) are generally "approximately" normal. One should be careful here.